# Strange behavior of macro __FILE__ with gradle

Tags: c, gradle

As you know, macro__FILE__ in c/c++ contain a path to file, from where it was compiled.
For example:

```
gcc test.c -o test
./test
test.c

gcc myFolder/test.c -o test
./test
myFolder/test.c
```

But when I try to compile with gradle, it output the full path to my file, like:

```
home/usr/myFolder/test.c.
```

I want to precompile macro__FILE__ contain only interior project path but not full.

Gradle File:

```
apply plugin: 'c'

model {
    components {
            main(NativeExecutableSpec) {
                    sources {
                        c {
                            source {
                                srcDir "./"
                                include "*.c"
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

test.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
    printf("%s\n", __FILE__);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately due to way how gradle invokes the compiler, this is expected. If you want to get just the relative project path, you can do something like

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
    printf("%s\n", __FILE__ + PROJECT_PATH_LEN);
}
```

and then add an appropriate define of `PROJECT_PATH_LEN` to `file("./").absolutePath.length` (see [gradle documentation on how to add defines](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/native_software.html#N18C89)).

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of `__FILE__` is clear: it is a macro that expands to the name of the current input file, in the form of a C string constant.

It is the path used by the preprocessor to open the file.

The fact that you get the whole path is to be expected.